# Second mail server for my domain

Tags: domain-name-system, email, postfix, spam

I have to setup a mail server because my hosting account don't allow me to send over 250 mail/hour.

I have a HP microserver at home and I want to use it to send the mails.
I configured Virtualmin on it and i created the domain example.com in it (I have example.com registered with hosting on my hoster) but when I tried to send mail from outlook, my server send the emails, but gmail mark it as spam...

I tried to add a dkim (maybe without success) to the dns, and I tried also to add an SPF record to my dns to allow my server to send mail like the other (the 'original' server where I have the site) but I receive the mail as spam.

What can I do?

Comment: Is the HP microserver hosted by yourself at home?

Comment: yes... I think with the 10M of my home it should work without problem to send mail...

Comment: do you have a static ip? If not then it's normal that your mail goes straight to spam, actually most mailservers will even refuse to take the mail you want to deliver to users from a dynamic ip address.

Comment: Yes of course, I have my static ip

Comment: And is your spf record something similar to:
`v=spf1 mx a:yourhomehostname -all`

Comment: my spf record is **v=spf1 mx a ptr ip4:2.232.158.77** and 2.232..etc is my ip...

Comment: in that case your spf is neutral, you're missing the -all directive

Comment: I used a tool to create the spf...adding '-all' it should change?

Comment: your IP is blacklisted at cbl, http://cbl.abuseat.org/lookup.cgi?ip=2.232.158.77 . but even if you solve that problem, you won't have much luck sending from a domestic connection, see adaptr's answer and get a real business ip or use smarthosting.

Comment: Home use questions are off-topic on Server Fault. Sending this volume of bulk mail from your home account is also almost certainly a violation of your ISP's terms of service.

Comment: I solved my problem using **auth-results[at]verifier.port25.com** ... thak you MartinoDino with **~all** and @Gryphius for the hint to the blacklist.. now it works very well.
however i'm not violating my ISP terms of service cause they never said me that I can't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FCrDNS (forward-confirmed reverse DNS) is where a given IP address has forward (name-to-address) and reverse (address-to-name) DNS entries that match each other.

Depending on how emails you send it, maybe you can spread it out over the course of 24 hours. Otherwise, I'd suggest upgrading to a higher package if ordered or finding another provider. Sometimes if you can prove you are not sending spam, they will raise your sending limit.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to usefully run a mail server without a static IP and proper FCrDNS configured.

The odds of you achieving this on a domestic connection are not good.

If you need more functionality than your current hosting contract allows for, perhaps it is time to upgrade.

Comment: What is FCrDNS?